# Displaying rank of user with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the rank of a user, and this is the current code that i have got.

The issue is it shows rank "2" all the time.

Where have i gone wrong?

```
   <?
     if(! defined('BASEPATH') ){ exit('Unable to view file.'); }
    $sql = $db->Query("SELECT uid, SUM(`total_clicks`) AS `clicks` FROM `user_clicks` GROUP BY uid ORDER BY `clicks` DESC");
    $user = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT uid, SUM(`total_clicks`) AS `clicks`, @rank := @rank + 1 as ranking
    FROM `user_clicks`, (select @rank := 0) r
    GROUP BY uid 
    ORDER BY `clicks` DESC");

    ?>

    RANK # <?=$user['ranking']?>
```

Comment: First: dont use short_open_tag, Second: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp

Comment: @Ikac ` dont use short_open_tag` why not?

Comment: tags <?php ?> are allowed on all servers, some administrators turn off short open tags bcs some servers dont allow and that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: so why is this showing 2 on any user that logs in?

Comment: @Ikac  `Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available`

Comment: PSR-1 force to se `<?php and ?>` `<? `However the use of this style is not recommended, although it is by default excluded system administrators it turns off because it can be a cause misinterpretation declaration in XML documents.

Comment: Why are you declaring rank as 'r' in the query?

Comment: http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/

Comment: im new to this im not sure what i am doing is taking code snipets that i find and trying to make this work, you see this is the best way for me to learn.